# PSR-4 not loading my project classes

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload, psr-4

I'm using Composer's PSR-4 to autoload classes, but it won't load my classes.
Every time I try to use one of my classes the app dies without any error, even though it should display error.

Here is my file structure:

```
/
│   composer.lock
│   composer.json
│   index.php
├───src
│       Array.php
│       File.php
├───vendor
        ...
```

composer.json - autoload part

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "FileManager\\": "src"
    }
}
```

Start of index.php

```
<?php

require(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');

var_dump(class_exists('Array'), class_exists('Array', false));
var_dump(class_exists('File'), class_exists('File', false));
```

And it dumps this:

```
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(false)
```

If I add

```
use FileManager\Array;
```

it will die instantly. If I add

```
use FileManager\File;
```

it won't die, but it won't recognize `File` class either.

I have ran

```
$ composer dumpautoload
```

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: You need to add a trailing slash after the target in your psr-4 declaration in the composer file: `"FileManager\\": "src/"`. Then run `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Didn't help. autoload-psr4.php still has this in array: `'FileManager\\' => array($baseDir . '/src'),`. Even after running `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: Did you run `composer dump-autoload` after changing the composer-file?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Yes, I did.

Comment: I just looked at a working autoload_psr4.php file. That is correct. That's how it's storing it (I also have without the trailing slash in that file). Have you set the namespace in the files `Array` and `File` correctly in the very top of the files? `namespace FileManager;`?

Comment: Yes, I have.
`<?php
 namespace FileManager;

 class Array {`

Comment: I just found out that autoloader is using some static loader, based on these conditions `$useStaticLoader = PHP_VERSION_ID >= 50600 && !defined('HHVM_VERSION') && (!function_exists('zend_loader_file_encoded') || !zend_loader_file_encoded());` in autoloader_real.php on line 26. Is there a way to disable static loading?

Comment: I'm stupid. A class with the name `Array` will obviously never work, since it's a _reserved word_ in PHP. In your php-ini, set "error_reporting" to E_ALL and enable "display_errors". Then restart your web server and you should see some error messages that will help you sort this out.

Comment: Don't mess with the auto loader. It's not likely that there's anything wrong with the generated code. Check my previous comment instead.

Comment: Enabled displaying errors and set error reporting to all. Put this in my index.php `use FileManager\File; $file = new File();`, and got this error `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'FileManager\File' not found in /var/www/html/index.php:8 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/index.php on line 8`. Also I have renamed Array class to ArrayUtil.

Comment: Can you share the content of `src/File.php`, `src/ArrayUtil.php`, and `index.php`?

Comment: I created new project and everything works now

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are passing `string`s to `class_exists()`.

If you use `string` values to reference class names, you will need to use the **fully-qualified class name**.

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

var_dump(
    class_exists('FileManager\ArrayUtil'),
    class_exists('FileManager\File')
);
```

Alternatively, you can use the `class` keyword (requires at least PHP 5.5):

```
<?php

use FileManager\ArrayUtil;
use FileManager\File;

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

var_dump(
    class_exists(ArrayUtil::class),
    class_exists(File::class)
);
```

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.dynamic.php
- http://php.net/manual/de/migration55.new-features.php#migration55.new-features.class-name
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class